# How to connect by solClientjs?

Tags: javascript, solace

I download solclientjs-7.1.1.3 demo from the website,and i wanna use the the sample connect to my own solace,but it doesn't work. The "readme" text file told that "To run the samples, you must configure a Solace appliance to accept connections from the samples. See the chapter 'Quick Start' in the API Developer Guide."I didn't find the way to configure a Solace appliance to accept connections.How to configure?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solace Javascript API makes use of the Web Messaging feature.
Do note that Web Messaging for a Solace physical appliance requires a separate product key to unlock. This is different from a VMR, which comes with Web Messaging unlocked.

Please verify the following:

1. If you are using a Solace physical appliance (not VMR), you need to have a Web Messaging product key.
   On the CLI, execute the following to verify.

```
solace> show product-key

Product Key : xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-x-xxxx
  Unlocked Features : 1
    WEB Transport Service
```

2. Verify that the Web Messaging service is enabled, and the configured Web Messaging port. The necessary lines to check are in bold. The default Web Messaging port is 80.

```
solace> show service

Msg-Backbone:       Enabled
  SMF:              Enabled
    Web-Transport:  Enabled
  REST Incoming:    Enabled
  REST Outgoing:    Enabled
  MQTT:             Enabled

...
                                         Status
Service  TP  S C R VRF   MsgVpn          Port  A O Failed Reason
-------- --- ----- ----- --------------- ----- --- ---------------------------
SEMP     TCP N - - Mgmt                     80 U U
SEMP     TCP Y - - Mgmt                    443 U U
SMF      TCP N N N MsgBB                 55555 U U
SMF      TCP N Y N MsgBB                 55003 U U
SMF      TCP N N Y MsgBB                 55556 U U
SMF      TCP Y N N MsgBB                 55443 U U
SMF      WEB - - - MsgBB                    80 U U
```